# PJSIP - Freepbx - Trunk Registration Rejected

Tags: sip, registration, pjsip, trunk, freepbx

I'm trying to register a SIP account to my provider. Actually on my FreePBX I have other 4 accounts on different servers registered without problems.

I cannot figure out because this specific account don't want to collaborate.

This is the log that asterisk return me on PJSIP

```
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_message_ip_updater.c: Re-wrote Contact URI host/port to 192.168.250.5:5060
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: No dialog serializer for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=9979 (rdata0x7f5014015068). Using request transaction as basis.
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found transaction tsx0x2949cb8 for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=9979 (rdata0x7f5014015068).
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found serializer pjsip/default-00000011 on transaction tsx0x2949cb8
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x23a5830: PJSIP tsx response received
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x23a5830: Cancelling timer
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x23a5830: Timer cancelled
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x23a5830: Callbacks executed
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x23a5830: wrapper destroyed
[2017-06-30 21:08:57] DEBUG[2825] res_pjsip/pjsip_configuration.c: Contact 390144485210/sip:8004001@sip.macrovoip.it:5060 status didn't change: Reachable, RTT: 26.417 msec
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] manager.c: Running action 'Login'
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x2579740: Wrapper created
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x2579740: Set timer to 3000 msec
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip/pjsip_message_ip_updater.c: Re-wrote Contact URI host/port to 192.168.250.5:5060
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: No dialog serializer for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=36024 (rdata0x7f5014015068). Using request transaction as basis.
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found transaction tsx0x2939138 for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=36024 (rdata0x7f5014015068).
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found serializer pjsip/default-00000012 on transaction tsx0x2939138
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x2579740: PJSIP tsx response received
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x2579740: Cancelling timer
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x2579740: Timer cancelled
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x2579740: Callbacks executed
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x2579740: wrapper destroyed
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[2825] res_pjsip/pjsip_configuration.c: Contact 390144485210/sip:8004001@sip.macrovoip.it:5060 status didn't change: Reachable, RTT: 23.996 msec
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] manager.c: Running action 'Command'
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract double from [3.0] in [-inf, inf] gives [3.000000](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract double from [3.000000] in [-inf, inf] gives [3.000000](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [60] in [0, 86400] gives [60](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [5060] in [0, 4294967295] gives [5060](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract double from [3.0] in [-inf, inf] gives [3.000000](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract double from [3.000000] in [-inf, inf] gives [3.000000](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [60] in [0, 86400] gives [60](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [5060] in [0, 4294967295] gives [5060](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract double from [3.0] in [-inf, inf] gives [3.000000](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract double from [3.000000] in [-inf, inf] gives [3.000000](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [60] in [0, 86400] gives [60](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [5060] in [0, 4294967295] gives [5060](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract double from [3.0] in [-inf, inf] gives [3.000000](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract double from [3.000000] in [-inf, inf] gives [3.000000](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [60] in [0, 86400] gives [60](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] config.c: extract uint from [5060] in [0, 4294967295] gives [5060](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] manager.c: Running action 'Command'
[2017-06-30 21:08:58] DEBUG[26619] manager.c: Running action 'Command'
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x262c960: Wrapper created
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x262c960: Set timer to 3000 msec
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip/pjsip_message_ip_updater.c: Re-wrote Contact URI host/port to 192.168.250.5:5060
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: No dialog serializer for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=20989 (rdata0x7f5014015068). Using request transaction as basis.
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found transaction tsx0x2ff8de8 for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=20989 (rdata0x7f5014015068).
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found serializer pjsip/default-00000013 on transaction tsx0x2ff8de8
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x262c960: PJSIP tsx response received
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x262c960: Cancelling timer
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x262c960: Timer cancelled
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x262c960: Callbacks executed
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x262c960: wrapper destroyed
[2017-06-30 21:08:59] DEBUG[2825] res_pjsip/pjsip_configuration.c: Contact 390144485210/sip:8004001@sip.macrovoip.it:5060 status didn't change: Reachable, RTT: 23.777 msec
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x3061f60: Wrapper created
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x3061f60: Set timer to 3000 msec
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip/pjsip_message_ip_updater.c: Re-wrote Contact URI host/port to 192.168.250.5:5060
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: No dialog serializer for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=50104 (rdata0x7f5014015068). Using request transaction as basis.
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found transaction tsx0x3016738 for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=50104 (rdata0x7f5014015068).
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found serializer pjsip/default-00000014 on transaction tsx0x3016738
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x3061f60: PJSIP tsx response received
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x3061f60: Cancelling timer
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x3061f60: Timer cancelled
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x3061f60: Callbacks executed
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x3061f60: wrapper destroyed
[2017-06-30 21:09:00] DEBUG[2825] res_pjsip/pjsip_configuration.c: Contact 390144485210/sip:8004001@sip.macrovoip.it:5060 status didn't change: Reachable, RTT: 23.365 msec
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x252cc30: Wrapper created
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x252cc30: Set timer to 3000 msec
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip/pjsip_message_ip_updater.c: Re-wrote Contact URI host/port to 192.168.250.5:5060
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: No dialog serializer for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=24416 (rdata0x7f5014015068). Using request transaction as basis.
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found transaction tsx0x294d3c8 for Response msg 200/OPTIONS/cseq=24416 (rdata0x7f5014015068).
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Found serializer pjsip/default-0000000d on transaction tsx0x294d3c8
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x252cc30: PJSIP tsx response received
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x252cc30: Cancelling timer
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x252cc30: Timer cancelled
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x252cc30: Callbacks executed
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x252cc30: wrapper destroyed
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[2825] res_pjsip/pjsip_configuration.c: Contact 390144485210/sip:8004001@sip.macrovoip.it:5060 status didn't change: Reachable, RTT: 26.968 msec
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[26656] manager.c: Running action 'Login'
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[26657] manager.c: Running action 'Login'
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[26658] manager.c: Running action 'Login'
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[26657] manager.c: Running action 'Command'
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[26657] manager.c: Running action 'Command'
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[26657] manager.c: Running action 'Command'
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[26657] manager.c: Running action 'Command'
[2017-06-30 21:09:01] DEBUG[26668] manager.c: Running action 'Login'
[2017-06-30 21:09:02] DEBUG[26696] manager.c: Running action 'Login'
[2017-06-30 21:09:02] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [3] in [0, 4294967295] gives [3](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:02] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [0] in [0, 4294967295] gives [0](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:02] DEBUG[2788] config.c: extract uint from [2] in [0, 4294967295] gives [2](0)
[2017-06-30 21:09:02] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x2ea78a0: Wrapper created
[2017-06-30 21:09:02] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip.c: 0x2ea78a0: Set timer to 3000 msec
[2017-06-30 21:09:02] DEBUG[2788] res_pjsip/pjsip_message_ip_updater.c: Re-wrote Contact URI host/port to 192.168.250.5:5060
[2017-06-30 21:09:03] DEBUG[2787] res_pjsip/pjsip_message_ip_updater.c: Re-wrote Contact URI host/port to 192.168.250.5:5060
[2017-06-30 21:09:03] DEBUG[26707] manager.c: Running action 'Login'
```

I'm very new to asterisk and to PJSIP especcially, I looked for the log but I cannot see evident mistakes. It seems to me to be as a loop, but as said I'm not so expert on asterisk.

A funny thing is that if I look to CHAN_PJSIP registration I see this:

```
Endpoint:  390144485210                                         Not in use    0 of inf
    OutAuth:  390144485210/8004001
        Aor:  390144485210                                       0
      Contact:  390144485210/sip:8004001@sip.macrovoip.it: fdc1ddb1bf Avail        24.328
  Transport:  0.0.0.0-udp               udp      0      0  0.0.0.0:5060
   Identify:  390144485210/390144485210
        Match: 195.223.107.151/32
```

It returns me that it is available.

Where is the error on my logs?

Thank You!